# Why are homogenous Sobolev spaces defined over distributions?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory, fractional-sobolev-spaces

For any $s \geq 0$ (integer or non-integer), the Sobolev space $H^s(\mathbb{R}^3)$ is defined as
$$H^s(\mathbb{R}^3) := \{u \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^3) : \|u\|_{H^s}^2 < \infty\}$$
where the norm is calculated in Fourier space:
$$\|u\|_{H^2}^2 := \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} (1 + |\xi|^{2s})|\hat{u}(\xi)|^2 d\xi.$$

The homogenous Sobolev space $\dot{H}^s(\mathbb{R}^3)$ is defined as:
$$\dot{H}^s(\mathbb{R}^3) = \Big\{u \in \mathcal{S}' : \hat{u} \in L^1_{\text{loc}} \quad \text{and} \quad \int_{\mathbb{R}^3}|\xi|^{2s}|\hat{u}(\xi)|^2 d\xi < \infty \Big\}$$
where $\mathcal{S}'$ is the set of tempered distributions (dual of Schwartz space). So in words it seems this is the set of all tempered distributions whose Fourier transforms are $L^1_{\text{loc}}$ functions with finite "norm".

I have two questions about this definition.

1. Why are we going from $L^2$ to $S'$ when defining the space itself? Is this to overcome some technical difficulty?
2. What is the motivation for such a space and how is it used in practice? As I understand it, the whole point of Sobolev spaces is to have complete spaces containing certain functions and some number of its (weak) derivatives. How does generalizing to distributions help us, especially in the context of PDE?

Comment: This is one definition, there are others (is this Bahouri-Chemin book?). Indeed, when $s\geq 0$, one could as well consider $u\in L^2_{\mathrm{loc}}$ in the definition. The second question is vague and has been discussed a lot on this forum already (trace spaces, spaces where one can prove existence or uniqueness, ...)

Comment: @LL3.14 How is it that the same space can be defined either using $L^p$ functions or distributions? I think this is the part that is causing me the most confusion.

Comment: In general, what will happen is $\dot{H}^s\cap L^2 = H^s$.

Comment: By Sobolev's embedding, any distribution in $H^s$ is in $L^p_{\mathrm{loc}}$ for some $p>2$ and so identifiable with a locally integrable function.

Comment: @LL3.14 Thank you!